# decltype and const reference return types for strings

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

Given a data member, _value, in a class, defined thus:

```
unique_ptr<std::string> _value = nullptr;
```

The following does not compile.

```
auto getValue() const -> const decltype(*_value) &
```

Compiler returns this error:

**‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘std::basic_string&'**

However if I declare the function like this:

```
auto getValue() const -> const remove_reference<decltype(*_value)>::type &;
```

It compiles and behaves as I want (i.e., essentially returns a const string&)

I find this strange.  Could it be a bug in the gcc compiler or is there some fundamental difference between the two declarations?

decltype(*_value) correctly evaluates to basic_string& which is find so I thought I could just stick a const in front of it and it should be find but seems to confuse the compiler...

Note that my intention is basically for the function to return a const reference to the type being pointed to by the unique_ptr.

Comment: GCC is broken in rejecting your first version (a bug that has since been fixed on GCC trunk), but that one also doesn't do what you want (the `const` is applied to the reference type, which is ignored, and after reference collapsing the function returns `std::string&`).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this was fixed in `gcc 5.0` which we can test online using [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox) but as T.C. notes const is ignored when applied to the reference, from the draft C++11 standard `8.3.2`:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced
>   through the use of a typedef-name (7.1.3, 14.1) or decltype-specifier (7.1.6.2), in which case the cv-qualifiers
>   are ignored.